# How does a function know what inputs to draw from when labeled under different names?

Tags: c++, parameters, cs50

How can `int length` and `int array[]` be labeled differently than `int TOTAL` and `int scores`, yet they are recognized as being the same in the `average()` function? I assumed they had to be called the same thing in order to be recognized?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float average();

const int TOTAL = 3;

int main(void)
{
    int scores[TOTAL];
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
        {
        scores[i] = get_int("Score: ");
        }

    printf("Average: %f\n", average(TOTAL, scores));

}

//int array [] same as saying int scores [] ?
//int 'length' same as saying 'TOTAL' ?
float average(int length, int array[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum / (float) length;
}
```

Comment: What material have you been using to learn the C++ language?  Parameter passing should be covered by any introductory chapter on functions.

Comment: Well, they are different variables. It's actually stranger that they *can* have the same name, at least until you learn about variable scopes.

Comment: Take a look at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: Ive been using the cs50 2020 videos on YT. I'll look into Parameter passing now, thanks for the direction paddy.

Comment: Thanks for the link cigien, didnt know that existed ill post future questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names in most programming languages have a certain "scope" that they apply to. In C/C++, scopes are often determined by regions between a `{` and `}` character, e.g. a function scope or a loop scope within it.

In this specific example, `TOTAL` is defined in the "global" scope. Anything after that line can see and access that variable. This is generally considered bad practice, because it "pollutes" the global scope. Imagine, what would happen if you added someone else's code that also defined `TOTAL` to be something else? Or worse, forgot to define it but used it anyway? Nothing good, I promise you.

All other variables in this example are defined in their own "local" scope. The name `scores` is usable `int main(void) { int scores... <HERE> } <but not here>`. Likewise, the name `array` is usable `average(int length, int array[]) { <HERE> } <but not here>`.

But how do you get data from one function to another? You call the function! From `main`, when you call `average(TOTAL, scores)`, you are referring to the name `TOTAL` from the global scope, and `scores` from `main`'s scope, and passing them as "*arguments*" or "*parameters*" to the function `average`. The function `average` defines its own names for those arguments, but they will still contain the data from the variables used where it is called.

This is an essential property of most programming languages. Without it, function callers would need to make sure their names don't conflict with the internal ones used by the functions they call, and vice-versa. The relevance of this mechanism might be more obvious with a different example:

```
// convert a temperature in celcius to farenheit
float c2f(float celcius) {
  return 1.8f * celcius + 32.0f;
}

// print the computer temperature sensor values in farenheit
void print_computer_temperatures(temperatures_t temps) {
  float gpu_temp = c2f(temps.gpu);
  float cpu_temp = c2f(temps.cpu);
  float chipset_temp = c2f(sys()->GetTemp(CHIPSET));
  float chassis_temp_c = -1;
  CoolerMasterQueryChassisTemp(&chassis_temp_c);
  float chassis_temp = c2f(chassis_temp_c);
  printf(...);
}
```

Comment: Okay, after reading over and over I think I understand it correctly. So what youre saying is that the title/name of the two ints written in the average function (length and array[]) are really just empty placeholders, that I then filled with the values TOTAL and scores, during the printf line of my main function? So overall, the average function was essentially just an empty formula waiting to be filled with value until my printf line was finished, upon which it called upon the values TOTAL and scores to fill in the variables length and array[]? I also assume that they both needed to be ints?

Comment: I couldn't fit my thank you. Thanks for the reply, I believe it was extremely helpful.

Comment: @DRB *"the average function was... waiting to be filled with value"* - exactly. A function is basically just a procedure with inputs (parameters) and outputs (return values). It's not until it's actually called by another function and provided with the inputs it needs that it gets executed. In fact, a function *declaration* (signature) doesn't even need names for the parameters, because they only apply to the *definition* (implementation).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the arguments are called positional.

This means, that when you define a function (`float average(int length, int array[]){...}`), `length` will be the firs argument and `array` will be the second. These names are not global and exist only inside the function.

When you call the function (`average(TOTAL, scores)`), you pass global (availiable from everywhere) variable `TOTAL` as the first argument, and a local for `main` function variable `scores` as the second argument.

`length` is not the same as `TOTAL`, it just gets the value of `TOTAL` when the function is called. Same for `array` and `scores`.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, the value of TOTAL was attributed to length and scores to array[], because the order in which they appear in the code, not their names? Thanks

Comment: @DRB Yes. Also, changing `length` inside the function will not affect `TOTAL`, since it was only the value of `TOTAL` that was put into `length`. Same for the array.